# Сохранение текста в поле textarea формы после обновления страницы

Tags: php, input, textarea

на сайте есть форма обратной связи, в ней 2 поля, одно input второе textarea, в поле input пользователи вводят свой email, в поле textarea свое сообщение, затем вводят капчу и нажимают кнопку отправить, после валидации происходит отправка сообщения, но если пользователь ошибся с решением капчи, то формы очищаются.
С полем input решил проблему с помощью value, а вот как сохранять введенный текст в поле texarea? Буду крайне признателен за любую помощь!
вот собственно сам код:

```
    $formcode="<form method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"return false\" 
    enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">

    <div class=\"form-group\">
    <label>".$lang[196]."</label>
    <input class=\"form-control\" id=\"send_email\" name=\"send_email\" type=\"text\" value=".@$_POST['send_email']."></div>

    <div class=\"form-group\">
    <label>".$lang[198]."</label>
    <textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" id=\"send_text\" name=\"send_text\"></textarea></div>

    <div class=\"form-group\">
    <label>".$lang[203]."</label>
    <a class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('hello_bot').src='code.gif?'+Math.random();return false;\">".$lang[2031]."</a><br /><br /><img alt=\"".$lang[203]."\" id=\"hello_bot\" src=\"code.gif?".microtime()."\" /><br /><input class=\"form-control\" id=\"securityCode\" type=\"text\" name=\"securityCode\" size=\"\"></div>

    <a class=\"btn btn-danger\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"sendFormMailToUser($('send_email').value, $('send_text').value, $('securityCode').value, ".$_REQUEST['idmess'].");return false;\">".$lang[199]."</a></form>";
```

Comment: Для сохранения, нужно использовать локальное хранилище в браузере, либо сессии на стороне сервера. Но я бы лучше смотрел в сторону `localStorage`, так как смысла нет напрягать этим сервер, ибо все это происходит на стороне клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
<textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" id=\"send_text\" name=\"send_text\">.$_POST['area_text'].</textarea>
```

Где `area_text` - ключ к тексту из TextArea, отправленному методом `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, к примеру, рабочий вариант того, что вам требуется.
Показан пример работы использования localStorage для сохранения данных, введенных в textarea.
P.S. Если нажать "Выполнить код", то не сработает, так как код в "песочнице" - скопируйте код целиком, сохраните как HTML-файл и откройте в браузере.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="editable" name="name" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <script>
    if (localStorage.getItem('text') !== null) {
      document.getElementById('editable').value = localStorage.getItem('text');
    }
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      localStorage.setItem('text', document.getElementById('editable').value);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```